Manuscript /ˈmæn.jəskɹɪpt/
I wonder whether the compulsory semivowel /j/ is related to its hyphenation (man‧u‧script). I am not aware of the algorithm or rules used for written hyphenation, but all sources seem to coincide.
Vol·un·tar·y shows a similar syllabification  but the -u- is always /ə/.
Therefore, maybe the etymologically related term manual /ˈmænjuəl/ exerts its influence on manuscript?

Hyphenation is determined by syllabification, not the other way around.

@Barmar A relationship, or correlation as it's known in the trade, is not the same as a causation ;-)

They're clearly related. If it weren't pronounced with the /j/ we could pronounce it as "ma noo script", and then it would be hyphenated as "ma-nu-script". But it wouldn't be possible to include /j/ in the first syllable.

@Barmar I had thought about a phenomenon similar to spelling pronunciation, so "hyphenation pronunciation".

manacle has different hyphenation and syllabification according to Merriam-Webster, being hyphenated man-a-cle but syllabified "ma-ni-kəl" so who knows if other man words are different?

Related.

Many American English speakers have simplified /nju/ to /nu/ in words like new, and as a result, generally don't have words starting with /nj/. One possible interpretation of this sound change would be that it represents a prohibition on starting a syllable with the consonant cluster /nj/. If we accept that interpretation, it would explain why /nj/ in words like manuscript is split between syllables. However, Merriam-Webster doesn't seem to follow this principle. The Merriam Webster entry for sternutation hyphenates it as "ster·​nu·​ta·​tion" and shows the pronunciation as "ˌstər-nyə-ˈtā-shən". It also gives poignant as "poi·​gnant ˈpȯi-nyənt". These examples imply that the Merriam-Webster hyphenation/syllabification of manuscript as "man·​u·​script ˈman-yə-ˌskript" is not based only on the following /j/ sound.
Another possible influence is the quality of the preceding vowel sound. The vowel in the first syllable of manuscript is short a, transcribed /æ/. This is what some phonologists call a "lax" vowel*: it's a vowel that doesn't usually occur at the end of a word (although there can be exceptions for some speakers) or before another vowel sound. As a result, many theories of syllabification or hyphenation suppose that it is necessary for the vowel sound /æ/ to be attached to at least one following consonant sound (in this case, /n/), at least when it occurs in a syllable that carries greater stress than the following syllable. Manuscript has stress on the first syllable and no stress on the second syllable.
Stuart F pointed out in a comment that Merriam-Webster hyphenates manacle as "man·​a·​cle" but shows its pronunciation as "ˈma-ni-kəl". Likewise, the first two syllables of manifest and manifold are transcribed by MW as "ˈma-nə-", but hyphenated as "man·​i·". This suggests that Merriam-Webster tends to avoid separating a lax/short/checked vowel from a following consonant in its hyphenations, but does not always avoid this in its pronunciation transcriptions.
Another example involving /nj/ is Kenya, given as "Ken·​ya ˈke-nyə".
My conclusion would be that Merriam-Webster seems to be following a consistent principle in hyphenating manuscript as "man·​u·​script", but its treatment of /nj/ in phonemic transcriptions seems inconsistent: it is usually split across syllables, but sometimes placed at the start of a syllable, even in words where it follows a lax/short vowel. I can't figure out why Merriam-Webster uses canyon "ˈkan-yən" on the one hand, but Kenya "ˈke-nyə" on the other.

*The term 'lax' is meant to avoid the imprecision of the traditional terms 'short' and 'long' as applied to English vowel phonemes: unfortunately, the tense/lax terminology is itself based on a phonetically dubious assumption that the traditional long vowels (phonetically diphthongs, such as /eɪ/) are consistently produced with a greater amount of articulatory 'tension' than the traditional short vowels (such as /æ/). When discussing phonotactics and phonology, it doesn't really matter which label you use for the class of short/lax vowels: another term is "checked vowels".

What about "ma-rim-ba"? Is that a different enough a that it doesn't need to be attached to the following consontant?

@Barmar: the first syllable of "marimba" is unstressed, and I pronounce its vowel as the schwa /ə/. Nobody considers it necessary for unstressed schwa to be attached to a following consonant, since it can be found regularly at the end of words (such as comma).

The only words with a similar closed structure are on the line of soluble, but then again phonetically is it not: /ˈsɑljəbəl/

@GJC: "soluble" has different vowels depending on accent. Cambridge transcribes it as /ˈsɒl.jə.b(ə)l/ US /ˈsɑːl.jə.b(ə)l/. The "short o" sound historically needed to be attached to a following consonant, but in American English it has transformed into the same vowel sound /ɑ(ː)/ as in "bra" or "spa", which can occur with no following consonant. Nevertheless, dictionaries of American English seem to syllabify it with the following L (e.g. MW sol·​u·​ble ˈsäl-yə-bəl).
